# configure tomcat7 and apache2

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, apache2

So I have tried several tutorials, however I am missing something and I hope someone could help me.

I have an **ubuntu 12.04** server running with **tomcat7** and **apache2** and I am trying to reach an application (JSF 2.2) running on tomcat via apache2.

The application running on tomcat is working perfectly fine if I am accessing it like this: *example.com:8080/demo*.

I am trying to access it via apache2 on the following URL: *demo.example.com*

So far the main page is loading, but the navigation within the application is not.

If the application is sending me to *example.com:8080/demo/page2.xhtml* **instead of *demo.example.com/page2.xhtml*** I am somehow redirected to 
**demo.example.com/demo/page2.xhtml** and get a HTTP Status 404.

And now the million dollar question: what am I doing wrong?

Here is my **httpd.conf** file:

```
<VirtualHost demo.mydomain.com:80>
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/demo/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/demo/

    <Proxy *>
            AddDefaultCharset Off
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the **server.xml** from tomcat7 I added the following entry:

```
<Connector port="8009" URIEncoding="UTF-8" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8080"/>
```

In the **libapache2-mod-jk "workers.properties"** I have the following entries:

```
workers.tomcat_home=/var/lib/tomcat7
workers.java_home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ps=/
worker.list=ajp13_worker
worker.ajp13_worker.port=8009
worker.ajp13_worker.host=localhost
worker.ajp13_worker.type=ajp13
worker.ajp13_worker.lbfactor=1
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=ajp13_worker
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update ProxyPass setttings as below.

```
 ProxyPass /demo/ ajp://localhost:8009/demo/
 ProxyPassReverse /demo/ ajp://localhost:8009/demo/
```

Or

```
 ProxyPass        /      ajp://localhost:8009/
 ProxyPassReverse /      ajp://localhost:8009/
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work -> I am redirected to the Parallels Plesk Panel homepage and the second one redirect's me to tomcat's default homepage, not the webapp running at "/demo".

Answer (score 0):

alternative you can use the http connector (default 8080). these must be activated in server.xml.

```
ProxyPass /demo/ http://localhost:8080/demo/
ProxyPassReverse /demo/ http://localhost:8080/demo/
```

if the URI /demo under /  to deliver, than follow configuration. For this, however, the links must be relative to demo, otherwise there will be problems

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/demo/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/demo/
```